# Replace by Child Fragment with SlidingTableLayout and ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I am new to android. I am trying to use the library support, and cannot find a way to use nested fragments with my current code structure.
I forked this github project: [AndriodMaterialDesignToolbar](https://github.com/tekinarslan/AndroidMaterialDesignToolbar). I reused the structure, in order to have two tabs, a list and a map, and it works. I want to have nested fragments in the tab that contains the list, like this:

```
MainActivity -> MapsFragment
             -> CategoryListItemFragment -> DetailItemFragment.
```

but cannot find a way to replace CategoryListItemFragment by the fragment that contains the detail of the item. I tried to solve it by using this:

```
            FragmentManager manager = getChildFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(fragmentID, DetailItemFragment.newInstance(i));
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
```

but don't know the ID of the container, since the fragment was added by the adapter, in the function getItem.

Here is the code of the main_layout, to clarify:

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark" />

        <com.test.discountapp.SlidingTabLayout
            android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/navdrawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navdrawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/white"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
</ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the code of my ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT =2;
    private int titles[];
    private Activity mActivity;

    public ViewPagerAdapter(Activity activity, FragmentManager fm, int[] titles2) {
        super(fm);
        titles=titles2;
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return CategoryListItemFragment.newInstance(titles[position]);
            case 1:
                return MapsFragment.newInstance(titles[position]);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mActivity.getString(titles[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in the replace() function does not refer to the fragment Id, but infact it refers to the id of the container.

replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment, String tag)

or

replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)

Refer to the official documentation here.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html

Comment: To replace a fragment in the viewpager, you will need to replace it in the adaper(fragment pager adapter or fragment state pager adapter ), then call notifydatachanged on the adapter.

Comment: Please see my update. I don't see which is the container I have to replace, since I don't have a <FragmentLayout or <fragment in my main_layout.